# RESTful API singular route with a single object to retrive and update (options parameters)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

Hi i'm stucked trying to create a route in the RESTful API server in express.

I've configured other routes and now i need to configure an `('/options)` or `('/profile')` singular route where there is only one object to retrive and update.

Basically i need to do the same of the [json-server module](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) in the [Singular routes](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#singular-routes) section.

So when i visit the `/options` endpoint i got the predefined object with this schema

```
{
  tax: Number,
  inps: Number,
  ritenuta: Number,
  banca: {
    nome: String,
    iban: String
  }
}
```

to update.

Here's my actual routes for `/options`:

```
var Option = require('../models/option');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/options')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    Option.find(function(err, options) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }

      res.json(options);
    });
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    var option = new Option(req.body);

    option.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }

      res.send({message: 'Option Added'});
    });
  });

// Save an option
router.route('/options/:id').put(function(req, res) {
  Option.findOne({ _id: req.params.id}, function(err, option) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    }

    for (prop in req.body) {
      option[prop] = req.body[prop];
    }

    option.save(function(err) {
      if (error) {
        return res.send(err);
      }

      res.json({message: 'Option updated!'})
    });
  });
});

// Retrive an option
router.route('/options/:id').get(function(req, res) {
  Option.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, option) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(error);
    }

    res.json(option);
  });
});

// Delete an option
router.route('/options/:id').delete(function(req, res) {
  Option.remove({ _id: req.params.id}, function(err, option) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    }

    res.json({message: 'Option deleted!'});
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

but it's much complicated. It should be simpler. In fact, in this case i need to get all the options, get the id of `options[0]` and make a call with the id as params to retrive the object and update.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? Is your code not working, or are you just asking for suggestions concerning improvements?

Comment: the code above is working. But it's complicated. It's the same of an article. You can Create, Read, Update and Delete. I need a simple solution that only allow me to Read and Update this field in poor words.

Comment: The real question is: "How to do if you have to store these default application values above in the database and give the user the ability to read and update that?"

Comment: If you need help improving code that already works, try going to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/